# pyserial receiving wrong data with the None

Tags: python-3.x, pyserial

when I write the bytes into serial, I get the data which I want, but there's a None appearing that my serial doesn't have this one.How can I delete the "None"?
Thanks!

```
#encoding = utf-8
import serial

def getValues():
    ser = serial.Serial('COM3', baudrate=9600, timeout=1)
    str = 'ZREADMACS'
    ser.write(bytes(str, encoding='utf8'))
    data = ser.readline()
    print(data)

while 1:
    # data = ser.readline()
    # if data:
    #     print(str(data)[2:63])
    # else:
    #     print(getValues())
    userInput = input('Are you kidding me?')
    if userInput == "1":
        print(getValues())
```

output like this, but I don't want "None".

```
Are you kidding me?1
b'client:TESTR~~address:R0003~~radiation:01000~~voltage:21000~~current:21000~~temprature:01000~~Li_power:02000~~time_delay:00010~~acs_712_zero:00000~~'
None
Are you kidding me?1
b'client:TESTR~~address:R0003~~radiation:01000~~voltage:21000~~current:21000~~temprature:01000~~Li_power:02000~~time_delay:00010~~acs_712_zero:00000~~'
None
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your code you call `print` twice.

On the first time you call it with `data` and `data` is assigned to the `readline` result.

On the second time, you call it directly on the `getValues()` result.

The problem here is that `getValues()` returns nothing so python translates it as `None` and then you print it.

If you remove the last `print` it will be good.

You can also add `return data` to your `getValues()` function.